# Using FontAwesome icons as submit buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Website using Bootstrap 3.3.6 and FontAwesome 4.6

I have a search form which consists of a text field and a button. All I want to do is use a FontAwesome icon `fa-search` (http://fontawesome.io/icon/search/) for the button.

The markup I have is this. The way this renders looks perfect but the button doesn't submit the form when clicked:

```
<form method="post" action="/somewhere">
<div class="col-lg-4 pull-right">    
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" class="form-control" maxlength="100" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search...">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
              </span>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Why does this not work? Is it not possible to use FontAwesome on submit buttons or something?

Comment: You need to use `<button type="submit">` or put in a Javascript function to trigger the form submit action. Otherwise, your code seems good.

Comment: @ShekharChikara thank you so much. Changing the button type to 'submit' works.

Comment: Happy to help! I have posted my comment as an answer, please accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `button` type to`submit` instead of `button`, since that will help in triggering the form `submit` event. So, your HTML should look something like this-

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also instead of button tag

```
<label for="submitBtn" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></label>
    <input id="submitBtn" type="submit" class="hidden" />
```